# Learning JavaScript: Is there a way to change the image file of a group of images without using individual ids?

Tags: javascript

Trying to teach myself JavaScript with a Tarot card program I plan on building on as I learn.

Right now I am trying to figure out how to change the image of a card from back to face when a user clicks on it, and I'm trying to do it all in JavaScript.

So far I've figured out how to change the img src with the card idea, but it only changes the first one. Is there a way to do this without having to write a separate function for each card? Or without using unique ids?

I've been researching for hours. I'm stuck.

```
<p align="center">

<img id="card" onclick="someFunc()" src="img-tarot-card-back-001.jpg">
<img id="card" onclick="someFunc()" src="img-tarot-card-back-001.jpg">
<img id="card" onclick="someFunc()" src="img-tarot-card-back-001.jpg">
<img id="card" onclick="someFunc()" src="img-tarot-card-back-001.jpg">
<img id="card" onclick="someFunc()" src="img-tarot-card-back-001.jpg">

</p>

<script>

   function someFunc() {
      document.getElementById('card').src="img-tarot-card-front-001.jpg";
   }

</script>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple images with the same id.  Use class and then pass `this` in the onclick event.

Comment: It's really nice to see someone who's learning the language recognise that a function is not needed per element... asking yourself that question repeatedly in the future when you write other apps willl make your code far more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of how to do it with your existing code, pass a reference to the image into your function within the HTML:

```
<img onclick="someFunc(this)" src="img-tarot-card-back-001.jpg">
                       ^^^^
                       "this" references the current image element
```

Note: I removed your `id` attribute, as IDs must be unique within a document.

Then update your function to use that instance:

```
function someFunc(card) {
    card.src="img-tarot-card-front-001.jpg";
} // Fixed this ending brace too
```

However, since you're just learning, you should start off on the right path. Try not to put Javascript in your HTML, it's bad practice. You should bind to those elements within your Javascript alone, for example:

```
document.querySelector("img") // Grab all <img> elements
    .addEventListener("click", function(e) { // Listen for a "click" event
        var clickedImage = e.target; // The clicked image will be stored in the target
        clickedImage.src = "img-tarot-card-front-001.jpg"
    });
```

Now your HTML is clean and Javascript-free:

```
<img src="img-tarot-card-back-001.jpg">
```

I used [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) here which are not supported on all browsers and are difficult concepts when just learning Javascript. However they are very important and if you can learn them now you'll set yourself up well for the future.

Comment: Thank you for the little bit of wisdom. It's nice to get guidance like that as you're learning. I am trying to implement your second solution but not having much luck, though I feel I understand the concept of your method clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick snippet, might be a good jump start for peoples passing by.

You have to choose between 78 cards. The deck can be shuffled without limit. A card when chosen is discarded from the deck. When 5 cards had been selected, they get revealed all together.

The cards, when selected, are pulled from this repository:

https://github.com/mcnuttandrew/tarot-deck

```js
let cards = [
  '00 The fool.svg',
  '01 The magician.svg',
  '02 The high priestess.svg',
  '03 The empress.svg',
  '04 The emperor.svg',
  '05 Hierophant.svg',
  '06 The lovers.svg',
  '07 The chariot.svg',
  '08 Strength.svg',
  '09 The hermit.svg',
  '10 Coins.svg',
  '10 Cups.svg',
  '10 Swords.svg',
  '10 Wands.svg',
  '10 Wheel of fortune.svg',
  '11 Justice.svg',
  '12 The hanged man.svg',
  '13 Death.svg',
  '14 Temperance.svg',
  '15 The Devil.svg',
  '16 The Tower.svg',
  '17 The star.svg',
  '18 The moon.svg',
  '19 The sun.svg',
  '20 Judgement.svg',
  '21 The world.svg',
  '2 Coins.svg',
  '2 Cups.svg',
  '2 Swords.svg',
  '2 Wands.svg',
  '3 Coins.svg',
  '3 Cups.svg',
  '3 Swords.svg',
  '3 Wands.svg',
  '4 Coins.svg',
  '4 Cups.svg',
  '4 Swords.svg',
  '4 Wands.svg',
  '5 Coins.svg',
  '5 Cups.svg',
  '5 Swords.svg',
  '5 Wands.svg',
  '6 Coins.svg',
  '6 Cups.svg',
  '6 Swords.svg',
  '6 Wands.svg',
  '7 Coins.svg',
  '7 Cups.svg',
  '7 Swords.svg',
  '7 Wands.svg',
  '8 Coins.svg',
  '8 Cups.svg',
  '8 Swords.svg',
  '8 Wands.svg',
  '9 Coins.svg',
  '9 Cups.svg',
  '9 Swords.svg',
  '9 Wands.svg',
  'Ace Coins.svg',
  'Ace Cups.svg',
  'Ace Swords.svg',
  'Ace Wands.svg',
  'King Coins.svg',
  'King Cups.svg',
  'King Swords.svg',
  'King Wands.svg',
  'Knight Coins.svg',
  'Knight Cups.svg',
  'Knight Swords.svg',
  'Knight Wands.svg',
  'Princess Coins.svg',
  'Princess Cups.svg',
  'Princess Swords.svg',
  'Princess Wands.svg',
  'Queen Coins.svg',
  'Queen Cups.svg',
  'Queen Swords.svg',
  'Queen Wands.svg'
];

let hats = [], hhh = 1;
cards.forEach((e) => {
  hats.push({content: `<h${hhh}><span data-card="${e}" class="back"></span></h${hhh}>`});
  (hhh >= 6) ? hhh = 1 : hhh++
})



let timer;

function loop5(){
  let i = 0
  clearInterval(timer)
  timer = setInterval(function(){
    shuffle()
    if (i >= 20){
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
    i++
  }, 200)
}
loop5()
function shuffle(){
   hats.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
   out.innerHTML = hats.map(e => e.content).join("")
}

let count = 0;
out.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.dataset.card && count < 5){
    cards.splice(e.target.dataset.card, 1);
    user.innerHTML += `<img class="blur" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcnuttandrew/tarot-deck/9e885d3608454a03f275c2c3375e9e9f45788b22/svgs/${e.target.dataset.card}">`
    e.target.outerHTML = ""

    document.querySelectorAll(".user > span")[count++].className = ""
    k(3,233,100); k(1,603,200);
  }
  if (count === 5){
    document.querySelectorAll("#user > img").forEach((e) => {
      e.className = ""
    })
    k(10,1233,100); k(3,1603,500);
    count++;
  }
})

// gain, frequency, duration
let a = new AudioContext()
function k(w,x,y){
  //console.log("Gain:"+w, "Hz:"+x, "ms:"+y)
  v = a.createOscillator()
  u = a.createGain()
  v.connect(u)
  v.frequency.value = x
  v.type = "square"
  u.connect(a.destination)
  u.gain.value = w * 0.01
  v.start(a.currentTime)
  v.stop(a.currentTime + y *0.001)
}
```

```css
body {background: midnightblue; color: antiquewhite;}
div, span {display: flex }
.user > span { max-width: 18rem; padding: 0 0 0 0.5rem; }
button {cursor: pointer }
.back {display: table-cell; background: black; height: 2.4em; width: 2.6em; border-radius: 0.2em; border: 2px blue solid}
.back:hover {filter: invert(0.2); cursor: pointer}
.out {display: flex;justify-content: center;flex-direction: row;}
.user {  display: grid;
  height: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;padding: 0 0rem 0 2rem;}
.card {height: 2.4em; width: 2.6em; }
img {width: 16vw }
.blur {filter: blur(10px);}
```

```html
<button onclick="loop5()">Shuffle cards</button> <b>Choose 5 cards</b>
<div id="out"></div>
<div class="user">
    <span class="">What is happening at the moment?</span>
    <span class="blur">How can I weather it easily and with grace?</span>
    <span class="blur">What is the lesson?</span>
    <span class="blur">What is leaving at this time?</span>
    <span class="blur">What is arriving at this time?</span>
</div>
<div id="user" class="user"></div>
```

Hint: Go full page, ask a question, and do not use it too much each days. Warmly.